What is not an applicaton of AI?
With the AI era, everyone says everything is AI, which doesn't seem to be the case. What is advertised as AI and isn't?
For example, (1) Google's PageRank algorithm is called AI, is it really AI? (2) Is a precise spinal column operation by a robot AI?
In summary, I'm looking for areas that claim to be using AI but, ultimately, aren't actually AI and it just marketing.

You may wish to look into the difference between AI and machine learning, which is a subfield within AI. AI is very broad.

@David Hoelzer, do you have any references where I can learn more about the broad scope of AI?

This question is similar to: What are the minimum requirements to call something AI?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is basically asking what AI is, so I think it's a duplicate of the linked question or this: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7838/2444. I think both should be in the duplicate questions, although they are slightly different. Or even this https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7624/2444.

Anyway, I think your question is actually a bit different than the others, but still an answer requires people to define AI.

It's difficult to answer your question because different people use or assume different definitions of AI. Nowadays, many people think that AI is just language models (e.g. tools like ChatGPT and Gemini), but it's not. AI is also not just machine learning.
So, to answer your question, we first need to define AI. We already have several questions that attempt to address this, so I'll not repeat the info there.

What are the minimum requirements to call something AI?
What is artificial intelligence?
What is the most general definition of "intelligence"?

I gave an answer to each of the questions above and clearly I recommend you read my answers.
Anyway, off the top of my head, I can't think of an area where people say they are using AI but they are not.
PageRank is an example of an algorithm that some people will categorize as AI. I cannot say that this is right or wrong. It really depends on your definition. It's a clever algorithm, but so is binary search or quick sort, and not many people call them AI. We could say that every clever algorithm is AI, but then you need to define clever.
I think it's important to keep in mind that AI is more about agents, goals and environments, not just algorithms. An agent, like us humans, will ultimately use algorithms to achieve goals in an environment.
