Random answer AI how close to n layered network?
Can a chat bot which gives a random answer from 50 or N questions to a question be called an Ai? How close is it to a human? Its lightning fast and offers more comfort sometimes. So is it benificial to use in chatbots ocassionally?

Hey. Welcome. We have many questions on the definition of intelligence, etc. See e.g. https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7624/2444 or any other linked questions. I also wrote a blog post on the topic: https://nbro.gitlab.io/blogging/2020/05/20/on-the-definition-of-intelligence/. Having said that,  you're asking many questions here and you should ask only one question.
